# django ORM : how to make an select query with OR between two fields

Tags: database, django, orm, select

I am new to django and need some quick help.
How will the following sql statement be translated in django ORM?

> SELECT * from table_name WHERE field1
>   = v1 OR field2 = v2

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Q-objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
Model.objects.filter(Q(field1=v1) | Q(field2=v2))
```